# Visual Studio 2013, TFS 2010 - 0x80070570

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

My Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 10 has started throwing errors when trying to view work items in tfs (2010). I can view, download and open source code.

Not a lot on mother google for this error. 
Things i have tried

1. Connecting / disconnecting from tfs
2. Deleting registry settings for visual studio
3. Patching Visual Studio
4. Connecting to a different tfs server
5. Uninstalling / Reinstalling visual studio and then coming back to original one

None of these worked (and on step 4 it didn't let me see work items on the other tfs server.) Before i uninstall windows 10 any suggestions?

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.ControlsCore,
>   Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The file or directory is corrupted and
>   unreadable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070570)

Answer (score 0):

Is TFS 2010 has all the updates installed?

Visual Studio/ Team Explorer version    TFS 2010 support notes
Visual Studio/Team Explorer 2013        Supported (RTM or latest update)

This is what i found in the [Client Compatibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/TFS/administer/requirements). Are you able to use browser to open the work item?